# Has anyone successfully compiled 2.2 and 2.1 android AOSP on Lion 10.7.2 (11c74)

Tags: android, xcode4, build, makefile, osx-lion

I need this badly. I have tried over a month now, and all my attempts result in more or less incomplete and imperfect builds.

1. I have got many errors on the building process most of which I managed to thwart by hook or by crook...

Most of the problems in compiling got solved when i moved to Xcode 3.2.6 instead of latest version(4.2 i think)

But the resulting emulator and tools in general are unusable, I haven't checked all of them , but emulator sucks on this build and runs nothing, the AVDs run fine on other emulators, and even when I upgrade platform tools to newer versions.

This makes me nervous because I can't determine how many of the output files are not compiled/linked properly.

Has anyone been successful in compiling aosp (2.1 or 2.2 or 2.3 for that matter) on osx lion ?

(Pl do not suggest using any other operating system etc.... building happens properly in linux and all is a well known)

Comment: You might be more likely to get an answer on XDA forums: http://forum.xda-developers.com/  In my experience on StackOverflow, we generally deal in app development and less in OS builds.

Comment: No but I have had 0 problems compiling AOSP on Fedora. My colleague also did it on Ubuntu.